# The page load, but didn't show up the content

Tags: django, server, ip

I'm trying to connect to the server with `IP_address_server:8000`, but the page load without ever wanting to connect.

In fact, I start a Django project, and I did `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. In the project `settings.py`, I've included `IP_address_server` in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` (on the server), but I got the same issue.

Could anyone be able to tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: exact error on the page?

Comment: @DeepakKumar In fact, I got `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`; the site can't be reached.

Comment: When you say server, do you mean nginx/apache webserver or django's inbuilt server that you initiate using `runserver`?

Comment: @DeepakKumar I pay 5$ per month for that service on www.zappycode.com/vultr; It is not the local server.

Comment: Does it work when you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS`  to `['*']` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are (really meant to)hosting your django application on cloud, you should not use django's inbuild server, that is `manage.py runserver`. Check official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), quoting here:

> Now’s a good time to note: don’t use this server in anything resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for use while developing. (We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers.)

Now, if I am wrong and your application is indeed hosted on Nginx/apache, check server logs, for Nginx, `/var/log/nginx/`, for Apache, `/var/log/apache2/`.

If not, you can follow some of Django deployment guides, eg [here](https://github.com/rogueleaderr/definitive_guide_to_django_deployment) or [here](http://python-deploy-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/django-deployment.html)

Comment: You are right. But either way the app should work. Either with built-in server or nginx. There is something else.

Comment: Try opening the port, 8000 in your case, use `sudo ufw allow 8000`